# Sharing game Center among several applications

Tags: iphone, game-center

I'm building separate iPhone and iPad versions of my game. Is it possible to share the same game Center between them (and among them and Lite versions too)?

Comment: this is probably better asked on [GameDev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

No. Each app has its own unique bundle identifier which accompanies a request to Game Center for leaderboard data etc.